# Get values from array of data from jquery data ajax object

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Hi I am trying to get attribute values from array of elements...

JQuery

```
   function sendM(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            type:'POST',
            url:'../business_logic/send_chat_user.php',       //URL
            data:{ u_id: <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']?>,c_id },  //Data

            beforeSend:function(){},
            success:function(data,status){                      //Data,status
            var item = $(data).hide().slideDown("slow");
            var el = $.parseHTML(data);
            var e = $("a", el).attr ("value"); // This only gives me single value.. I want an array

            $('#msg').append(item);
            }
        });
}
```

send_chat_user.php file

```
   echo '<ul class="nav nav-list">';
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($list) ; $i++)
        {
            echo '<li>';    
            echo '<div class="user_list">';
                echo '<img src="../images/default_profile_pic/d_boy.png" class="img-rounded">';
                echo '<a href="#" value="'.$list[$i]['c_id'].'" data-toggle="c_id" id="c_id">'.$list[$i]['fn'].' '.$list[$i]['ln'].'</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }

    echo '</ul>';
```

I want to get array of values from attribute 'value' of Anchor tag . I am able to get single value in jquery in variable e ... but i want array of values.

Comment: there is no value for a http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html

Comment: That doesn't mean he cant get/set an added value attribute. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../business_logic/send_chat_user.php',       //URL
        data:{ u_id: <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']?>,c_id },  //Data

        beforeSend:function(){},
        success:function(data,status){                      //Data,status
            var arr = [];
            var item = $(data).hide().slideDown("slow");
            var el = $.parseHTML(data);
            var e = $("a", el);
            e.each(function(index) {
                arr.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });

            alert(arr.toString());

            $('#msg').append(item);
        }       
});
```

Comment: yes similar to this ... i hv printed arr but it shows only the object

Comment: You would have to use arr.toString() to print an array's contents or loop through it.

Comment: still undefined. actually i wanted to apply it on 'data' which is returned by ajax